# How to find Domain & Username from a line in text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to extract domain\username from text file.

### Sample Line to extract domain\username only:

```
<![LOG[The logged on user is LEO\userpc]LOG]!><time="02:42:14.378+420" date="09-09-2021" component="execmgr" context="" type="1" thread="6460" file="execreqmgr.cpp:5003">
```

Code i tried:

```
$filter  = Get-Content C:\Windows\ccm\logs\execmgr.log  | Where-Object { $_.Contains("LEO") } | select -Last 1 

$fil = $filter.Replace('<![LOG[The logged on user is ','')

Get-Content $fil | ForEach-Object {
  if ( $_ -match '^LEO' ) {
    $_ -replace '-', 'x'
  }
  else {
    $_
  }
}
```

Comment: "I tried RegEx, but no luck." - looks like you forgot to include your attempt(s) in the post

Comment: added tried code.

Comment: Something like `([regex]'The logged on user is\s+([^\]]+)').Match((Get-Content -Path 'C:\Windows\ccm\logs\execmgr.log' -Raw)).Groups[1].Value` perhaps?

Comment: Can powershell parse log files like cmtrace or trace32 does?

Comment: @Theo Please consider posting your suggestion as an answer instead.

Comment: @Dennis You're right; done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strings like that, I would use a regex like this:

```
([regex]'The logged on user is\s+([^\]]+)').Match((Get-Content -Path 'C:\Windows\ccm\logs\execmgr.log' -Raw)).Groups[1].Value
```